# Yii: CMarkdown with CGridView & CListView

Tags: php, yii

How can I enable Markdown formatting for a specific column in GridView and ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom functions to process columns. If you have PHP 5.3 you can do it the following way:

```
'columns'=>array(
  array(
    'name'=>'My markdown column',
    'value'=> function($data, $row){
        $parser = new CMarkdownParser();
        // if data is entered by user you can purify it using safeTransform
        return $parser->transform($data);
     }
  ),
)
```

For PHP <5.3 it's the same except you should wrap your code into a string and avoid using anonymous function.